# strcpy function with dynamic allocated char array

Tags: c++, pointers, char, new-operator, strcpy

I am facing problems to make this piece of code work:

```
char **createCharArray() {
    char **charArray = new char*[PARAM_COUNT];
    for (int i = 0; i < PARAM_COUNT; ++i) {
        charArray[i] = new char[MAXSIZE];
    }
    return charArray;
}
 
void deleteCharArray(char **charArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < PARAM_COUNT; ++i) {
        delete[] charArray[i];
    }
    delete[] charArray;
}    

int main(){
    char ** test = createCharArray(); 
    char *asd = new char[MAXSIZE];
    cin >> asd;

    for (int i = 0; i < PARAM_COUNT; ++i) {
        strcpy_s(test[i], asd);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < PARAM_COUNT; ++i) {
        cout << i << " " << test[i] << endl;
    }

    deleteCharArray(test);
    return 0;
}
```

How do I copy that string into the char array, where am I mistaking?

Edit: As answered by Igor Tandetnik and user17732522 in the comments and Joseph Larson in the reply below, this was solved by adding the buffer argument to the strcpy_s function, making it a total of 3 arguments.

Comment: *How do I copy that string into the char array?* -- What's wrong with the code you have now?  Are we to assume that the secret `createCharArray` has no bugs?  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: In C++, the right way is to use strings and vectors.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/s9CLy3ZU - Here's the function. strcpy_s gives the following message: "could not match char[_size] against char *"

Comment: `strcpy_s` takes three parameters, not two.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It is a MSVC-specific `strcpy_s`, not the standard C one.

Comment: @user17732522 Even so, it takes three parameters, or two parameters of which the first is a char array. The code shown doesn't follow either pattern.

Comment: _"Cannot use strings and vectors"_ - Then I would use the documentation for `std::string` and create my own `std::string`-like class and only focus on the basic functionality that you need at the moment.

Comment: @Nik As mentioned above, `strcpy_s` takes either an array of `char`, or three arguments. You cannot use the two argument version with a `char` pointer. Neither of these are standard C++.

Comment: @Nik You still haven't specified what in the code "doesn't work".  If it is a compilation error, please post the error message.

Comment: error C2660: 'strcpy_s': function does not take 2 arguments 
However when I used it the same way with a locally created char array it worked with 2 arguments

Comment: okay, i tried adding a 'buffer size' argument in the middle of those 2 and I think it's working now

Comment: “Cannot use strings and vectors” why? Is that a homework assignment? A programming challenge? Without context this sounds like an xy problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I find troublesome. First, you've seen people say you should use std::string instead of char arrays, and that's true. But new programmers should understand the entire language, and so understanding how to use char arrays has value.

So let's ignore C++ strings and look at your code:

```
char ** test = createCharArray(); // array of pointers to char arrays
char *asd = new char[MAXSIZE];
cin >> asd;

for (int i = 0; i < PARAM_COUNT; ++i) {
    strcpy_s(test[i], asd);
}

for (int i = 0; i < PARAM_COUNT; ++i) {
    cout << i << " " << test[i] << endl;
}

deleteCharArray(test);
return 0;
```

Let's start with this. We don't know what `createCharArray()` does. Is it doing everything it should? Not only should it create an array of char pointers, but the way you're using it, it also needs to create the buffers they each point to. So it might look something like this:

```
char ** createCharArray() {
   char ** array = new char *[PARAM_COUNT];
   for (int index = 0; index < PARAM_COUNT; ++index) {
        array[index] = new char[MAXSIZE];
   }
   return array;
}
```

If yours looks remarkably different, you may have issues.

After that, let's look at this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PARAM_COUNT; ++i) {
    strcpy_s(test[i], asd);
}
```

As others have said, this version of `strcpy_s` takes three arguments:
strcpy_s(test[i], asd, MAXSIZE);

Note that you're copying the same string into place multiple times. I wonder if your code should really do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PARAM_COUNT; ++i) {
    cin >> asd;
    strcpy_s(test[i], asd, MAXSIZE);
}
```

And finally, the delete method needs to delete the individual pointers and then the array of pointers.